# grep the count of the numbers in a file

Tags: bash, grep

```
grep -c '[^\ ]\{7,\}' file.txt
```

gives me Word count longer than  7 characters.
But How do we get word count less than 5 characters and anything like range in between of length between 5 and 7 
characters .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get count of lines with less than 5:

```
grep -c '\<[^ ]\{1,5\}\>' file
```

For 5 to 7:

```
grep -c '\<[^ ]\{5,7\}\>' file
```

`\<` and `\>` are used for word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Please can you tell how to grep the number of words
beginning with vowels and the number of words beginning with
consonants in file . Never mind off the topic.

Comment: For starting with vowels: `grep -ic '\b[aeiou][^ ]\{1,5\}\b' file` and for consonants: grep -ic '\b[^aeiou][^ ]\{1,5\}\b' file

Comment: `grep -ic '\<[aeiou][^ ]\{1,5\}\>' file` is matching words starting with any letter in character class `[aeiou]` and other one is `[^aeiou]` which means match not starting with `a,e,i,o,u`.

Comment: But it works with line and not words. I mean it is considering lines . I want total words starts with vowels in a file

Comment: Then you can use: `grep -io '\<[aeiou][^ ]\{1,5\}\>' file | wc -l`

Comment: Yep.. Working .. :-) Thanks @anubhava

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> anything like range in between of length between 5 and 7 characters .

```
grep -c '\b[^ ]\{5,7\}\b' file.txt
```

Fopr word count less than 5.

```
grep -c '\b[^ ]\{1,4\}\b' file.txt
```